# Multiple JOIN on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm working on a messaging system on Laravel and I have the following tables :

USER

```
user_id | email | password | name | ...
---------------------------------------
```

CHAT

```
chat_id | user1_id | user2_id
-----------------------------
```

MESSAGE

```
message_id | content | date | user_id | chat_id | ...
------------------------------------------------------
```

and what I want to do, is to get all the chats the authenticated user have started with an other one, ordered by the date of the messages (from the most recent to the oldest one), plus the information on the user he's talking to.

I'm currently working on the raw SQL request before passing it in Laravel and this it what I try but it doesn't give the waited result :

```
SELECT user.user_id, user.name, user.surname
FROM user
JOIN chat a
ON user.user_id = a.user1_id
JOIN chat b
ON user.user_id = b.user2_id
WHERE b.chat_id IN
    (SELECT chat_id 
     FROM chat 
     WHERE user1_id = 1 OR user2_id = 1) 
AND user.user_id != 1  

----> (I'm testing with the user that has the ID #1)
```

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what are you expecting it to return and what does it return instead?

Comment: For example, The chat table has 2 records : chat_id : 1 - user1_id : 1 - user2_id : 2 //  chat_id : 2 - user1_id : 1 - user2_id : 3.

What I expect to have is for each row, the chat_id, the user_id, name, and surname for the user_id #2 and #3, but this returns an empty response. I'm still trying other SQL requests atm

Comment: If you only care for the user2_id why are you joining user on chat with a.user1_id?

Comment: Because I don't know in what column the user_id has been stored at the chat creation (if the user #1 start the chat, it will be stored in the user1_id, if he doesn't start it but receive a message, it will be stored in the user2_id)

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think if you post sample date and desired results in your question, you will get an answer.

Comment: Ok I'll try to be more clear ... as you have seen in my model, in the chat table, I have 2 references to "user_id" on the user table. When I start a chat, for example between the user #1 and #2, the user #1 id will be stored in the user1_id column and the user #2 in the user2_id column in the chat table. But it's possible that the user #1 is stored in the user2_id column, and the user #2 in the user1_id column in the chat table. WHAT I want to do, is to get all the information about the other user + the chat_id of the chat the authenticated user has started with this other user...

Comment: whoever starts first is in user1_id?

Comment: Yes that is it.

Comment: so in your query, you want all records in the chat table where the user with the id 1 in there, doesn't ,matter if they the ones started the chat or not. and you want to get the other users info?

Comment: Yes, I want the other users info, and the chat_id of the chat between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Union to get both results as follows:

```
select a.user1_id, a.chat_id, user.fname, user.lname 
from user
join chat a on a.user2_id = user.user_id and a.user1_id = 1
union 
select b.user2_id, b.chat_id, user.fname, user.lname 
from user
join chat b on b.user1_id = user.user_id and user2_id = 1
```

Comment: I just added the other user_id in the select but that perfectly works, thank you very much. I didn't think about using a Union because i'm not used to it, but it seems to be efficient

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it by clicking in the check. Thanks.